# TCL & IMAP - Fetch raw .eml file

Tags: imap, tcl, fetch

I'm learning TCL and am trying to create a TCL project which uses IMAP to get unarchived messages and then add them to my database. I have the basics for connecting, login, fetching and reading data all working but now I'm confused as how to get the file and save it.

Is it possible to save the file directly or do I need to somehow create a file myself after fetching the header, body text, attachments etc individually?

P.S.

Any thing I found on the subject is in PHP / C# or anything but TCL! and they all have inbuilt functions to fetch the data and then save it. I have found TCL's imap4 library but it doesnt seem to have the same capabilities as PHP.

Comment: Hi Keith. I'm afraid I don't fully understand your question. What is this "file" you refer to? Why do you mention a database?

Comment: Sorry I meant the email, to get the entire email and all information and save it then locally. and the mention of a database was just to explain why I am asking this question, and what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
FETCH <message ID> BODY.PEEK[]
```

to get the complete message (body+headers).

Answer (score 2):

From what I see on the internets, ".eml" is what older softwate calls "mbox format", that is, it's just a plain text file which contains an e-mail message as it's being transferred over the wire using SMTP.

And from what I see in the [section about the "FETCH" command  in the IMAP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#section-6.4.5), the `FETCH FULL` command is what supposedly fetches the full contents of a given message.

Since writing something to a file in Tcl is a no-brainer, I'd just try this route:

1. Use `FETCH FULL` to get the full message;
2. Open a file with a name ending in ".eml" in write/append mode, configure the resulting channel to have "binary" semantics (by calling `chan config $fd -translation binary`);
3. Write the fetched contents there, close the file.

Then verify how this worked by trying to import the resulting file into Outlook or Thunderbird or whatever.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent answer, I'm having trouble with the chan command but maybe I just need to update my TCL version, then I'll give it a shot!

Comment: @KeithBurke, the `chan` command appeared in 8.5. If you have an older version, use `fconfigure $fd -translation binary` instead (I also works in 8.5+ of course).

Comment: Sorry for the really late reply but this didn't actually work, when I do it I get:
* 1 FETCH (FLAGS (\Seen NonJunk) INTERNALDATE "26-Oct-2011 16:33:20 +0200" RFC822.SIZE 1732 ENVELOPE ("Wed, 26 Oct 2011 16:33:19 +0200" "=?ISO-8859-1?Q?grpicm_35436_ge=E4ndert_von_wr?=" ((NIL NIL "system" "grp.de")) ((NIL NIL "system" "grp.de")) ((NIL NIL "system" "grp.de")) ((NIL NIL "kb" "grp.de")(NIL NIL "keu" "grp.de")) ((NIL NIL "wr" "grp.de")) NIL NIL "<01cc93ec$Blat.v2.6.2$349b336a$1d1474632118@nts02>") BODY ("text" "plain" ("charset" "ISO-8859-1") NIL NIL "8BIT" 150 5))
C OK Fetch completed.

Comment: @KeithBurke, I've just performed the "View raw message" action from my MUA (I'm using Sylpheed) while peering at the IMAP traffic using Wireshark. Fetching a full message looks like this in terms of IMAP: http://pastebin.com/9HhABCYc  So I think it's an exercise for you to translate the MUA's command (the first line) into that Tcl package's terms.

Comment: `FULL` is equivalent to `(FLAGS INTERNALDATE RFC822.SIZE ENVELOPE BODY)`, and `BODY` is "Non-extensible form of `BODYSTRUCTURE`", which is not what you expect to be the raw message. You should use `BODY.PEEK[]`.